# Парсер. BS4. немного запутался в функциях, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Не так давно изучаю Python, пишу свой первый парсер, хочу брать цены на одно оборудование с одного сайта)

все просто. Одна функция загружает документ, другая собирает ссылки с главной страницы, третья собирает название и цену с конкретного товара 4я записывает в CSV.

почему то третья функция проходится по главной стр, и не видит ссылки собранные во второй в список links.
что я сделал не так, как передать этот список в 3ю функцию чтобы она проходила по нему а не по главной?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def get_html(url):  # получаем HTML код
    req = requests.get(url=url)
    return req.text


def get_links(html):  # получаем список ссылок с главной страницы
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    links_bad = soup.find_all(class_='title-sc')
    links = []
    for i in links_bad:
        a = i.find('a').get('href')
        link_good = 'https://tdlider.ru' + a
        links.append(link_good)
    return links


def item_data(html):  # получаем информацию с каждой ссылки
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    try:
        name = soup.find('div', class_="tovar-title").find('h1').text
    except:
        name = "нет имени"
    try:
        price = soup.find('div', class_="post-price").text
    except:
        price = "Нет цены"

    data = {"name": name,
            "price": price
            }
    return data


def write_csv(data):  # Пишем все в CSV
    with open("pricelist_lider.csv", "w", newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow
        (
            (data['name'],
             data['price'])
        )
    print(data['name'], 'parsed')


def main():  # Главная функция, которая собирает все.
    url = 'https://tdlider.ru'
    all_links = get_links(get_html(url))
    for url in all_links:
        if url != "https://tdlider.ru#":
            html = get_html(url)
            data = item_data(html)
            write_csv(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Ссылки парсер собирает корректно, в нём другие проблемы:

1. Неправильный режим открытия файла, с режимом "w" файл будет перезаписываться, а не добавлять строки, поменяйте режим на "a" в функции *write_csv*, чтобы строки добавлялись. Или предварительно соберите все данные в один список и один раз запишите.
2. Вы пытаетесь не тот элемент найти, он существует на странице конкретного товара, а не в каталоге.

Самое первое решение вопроса что пришло мне в голову это вытащить все блоки с товарами, а затем наименование и цену:

```
def item_data(html):
    data_list = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    cells = soup.find_all("div", class_="cat-post-cell")
    for cell in cells:
        name = cell.find("div", class_="title").text
        price = cell.find("div", class_="post-price")
        if price:
            price = price.text
        else:
            price = "Нет цены"
        data_list.append([name, price])
return data_list
```

Код немного изменился, и вместо словаря передаются вложенные списки и запись в csv будет выглядеть так:

```
def write_csv(data):
    with open("pricelist_lider.csv", "a", newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for line in data:
            writer.writerow(line)
            print(line[0], "parsed")
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за развернутый ответ :)